# Matlab : Group data using moving window over column value

Tags: matlab, sliding-window

I'm new to Matlab and would like to ask how to code a moving window in Matlab.

I've two columns of climate data (2x301491) in a txt file, the first of which is modified Julian date (MJD) and the second column is my data, which looks like this:

| MJD | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 57385 | 0.296 |
| 57385 | 0.3252 |
| 57385 | 0.2896 |
| 57386 | 0.0135 |
| 57386 | 0.0382 |
| 57386 | 0.0178 |
| 57386 | 0.0338 |
| 57387 | 0.1724 |
| 57387 | 0.1337 |
| 57387 | 0.1149 |
| 57388 | 0.2454 |
| 57388 | 0.2958 |

I'd like to group and save my climate data to a new txt file and rename it to MJD+18day based on an 18-day moving window that refers to MJD in the first column (the MJD ranges from 57385 to 57756) and run through each MJD value individually until the last 18 days.

All of the solutions I found for moving windows were based on number of rows rather than column values.

How can I solve this in Matlab in a loop? Thank you.

Comment: Any code which works on `rows` can easily be adapted to work on `columns`, and/or you could use [`transpose`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) to reshape your original data. The major problem with your question is you do not explain what you want to do with your data. "_group them based on a 18 days windows_" is unclear. Once you have selected a window of 18 days, do you `sum` the data, do you `average` them, do you do a product ? .... Also, do you want an output point per day, or one per group of 18 days?

Comment: Hello Hoki. I apologise if my question is unclear; Fortunately, I've already solved the problem. I forgot that the loop condition can be anything other than the number of rows. I was able to solve it by using: for i = mjd(1) : mjd(end)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
hp = tab(tab(:,1) >= i & tab(:,1) <= i+18,:); n=sprintf('%d.txt',i+18);  writematrix(num2str((hp),'%.6f'),n); if i+18 >= mjd(end) break; end end